# Haskell, find tupel that has minimum 2nd element ,if there are tupels with two same value of 2nd element, then sort with 1st element

Tags: haskell

example:  `mymin1 [(3,7),(7,6),(6,6),(5,6)]`     should returns `(5,6)`

this is my code:

```
mymin1 [(x,y)]=(x,y)
mymin1 ((x,y):(x1,y1):xs)
  |y>y1 = mymin1 ((x1,y1):xs)
  |y<=y1 =mymin1 ((x,y):xs)
  |y==y1 = if x>x1 then mymin1((x1,y1):xs) else mymin1((x,y):xs)
```

which returns `(7,6)`

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to rewrite your solution by taking only the first touple while pattern matching the list: `mymin1 [(x,y):xys] = ...` and recurse by `xys`. IMO there's an inherent logic error in trying to go with matching _2 touples_ and recursing in the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell already has an `Ord` instance for pairs of elements that each have `Ord` instances, but the instance for pairs compares the first elements before the second.  One solution that was already posted is to use `minimumBy` and supply your own comparing function, but another is to use `swap` liberally:

```hs
import Data.Tuple (swap)

myMin :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
myMin = swap . minimum . fmap swap
```

---

If you're super concerned about performance, you might be worried that we're traversing the list twice.  One way to address this is to use `coerce` to do a type-safe coercion rather than `fmap`ing `swap`, but that means we need a data type that is coercible to `(a,b)`.  If you're doing a lot of these comparisons, you could consider creating:

```hs
newtype Swap a b = Swap { getSwap :: (a,b) }
  deriving(Eq)

instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (Swap a b) where
  compare (Swap (a, b)) (Swap (c, d)) = compare (b,a) (d,c)
```

With this, you can then write `myMin` as:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
import Data.Coerce (coerce)

myMin :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
myMin = getSwap . minimum @[] . coerce
```

(Note that because `minimum` is polymorphic over the container type and we're using `coerce`, we need to tell GHC which type of container we're using.  Thus, we use the type application `@[]` after `minimum`.)

Comment: I think your first solution implements the function asked for, but the refinements using Down are all incorrect because they still look at the first element first, not the second.

Comment: In particular, the last two implementations of `myMin` appear to just implement, confusingly, `maximum`!

Comment: @amalloy Oh, you're totally right!  I got so carried away thinking about the wrong thing there...  I'll fix it.

Comment: I don't think your fixed version compiles at all. The patterns in `compare` should be `(Swap (a, b))`. Have you timed whether this is faster than the `swap`/`fmap swap` solution? I'm unsure: you avoid traversing the list twice, but in exchange you're swapping each tuple more often.

Comment: @amalloy Yup, that was a syntax error (fixed now).  Thanks for keeping me honest :).  Also, great job in your answer of doing the actual performance comparisons!

Answer (score 6):

I suggest just implementing the comparison function, and then using Data.List.minimumBy. You can implement the comparison function very easily using Data.Ord.comparing and Data.Tuple.swap.

```
myMin :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
myMin = minimumBy (comparing swap)
```

Since DDub's answer talks about performance concerns but doesn't actually time anything, I wrote a benchmark suite to compare the three approaches (mine, and the two in DDub's answer). I also added another version using `minimumBy` but building a custom comparator by hand, in case there is overhead in the `comparing swap`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
module Main where

import Criterion.Main

import Data.Coerce (coerce)
import Data.List (minimumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.Tuple (swap)

newtype Swap a b = Swap { getSwap :: (a,b) } deriving Eq

instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (Swap a b) where
  compare (Swap (a, b)) (Swap (c, d)) = compare (b,a) (d,c)

fmapMin, coerceMin, comparingMin, primitiveMin :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> (a, b)
fmapMin = swap . minimum . fmap swap
coerceMin = getSwap . minimum @[] . coerce
comparingMin = minimumBy (comparing swap)
primitiveMin = minimumBy cmp
  where cmp (a, x) (b, y) = case compare x y of
                              EQ -> compare a b
                              result -> result

input :: [(Int, Int)]
input = [(abs $ 25 - x, abs $ x - 25) | x <- [0..50]]

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain $ [env (pure input) (\xs ->
                                         bgroup "min"
                                         [ bench "fmap" $ nf fmapMin xs
                                         , bench "coerce" $ nf coerceMin xs
                                         , bench "comparing" $ nf comparingMin xs
                                         , bench "primitive" $ nf primitiveMin xs
                                         ])
                     ]
```

I guessed in a comment that DDub's two answers might perform similarly, but in fact DDub is right: the solution with coerce is substantially better. The `coerce` solution, and my two solutions with `minimumBy`, have basically indistinguishable performance. Here are the results:

```
benchmarking min/fmap
time                 580.6 ns   (577.9 ns .. 583.3 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 580.9 ns   (579.1 ns .. 584.2 ns)
std dev              8.058 ns   (5.348 ns .. 12.76 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 13% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking min/coerce
time                 195.9 ns   (195.0 ns .. 196.7 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 196.1 ns   (195.2 ns .. 197.9 ns)
std dev              4.159 ns   (2.337 ns .. 7.982 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 29% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking min/comparing
time                 193.5 ns   (193.2 ns .. 194.0 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 193.9 ns   (193.4 ns .. 195.1 ns)
std dev              2.529 ns   (1.302 ns .. 4.541 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 13% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking min/primitive
time                 194.1 ns   (193.5 ns .. 194.8 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 194.5 ns   (193.8 ns .. 196.2 ns)
std dev              3.447 ns   (1.640 ns .. 6.429 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 22% (moderately inflated)
```